# How to load Heyoffline.js with Require.js

Tags: javascript, requirejs, js-amd

I'm trying to load [Heyoffline](https://github.com/oskarkrawczyk/heyoffline.js) using require.js
I tried shim config

```
require.config({
    paths : {
        heyoffline  : "libs/heyoffline"
    },
    shim: {
        'heyoffline': {
            exports: 'Heyoffline'
        }
    }
});
```

And inside a module file.

```
define(["heyoffline"], function (Heyoffline) {
  new Heyoffline;
}
```

Other deps are loading without problems.

And I only get following exception:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Comment: What line is that error being reported from?

Answer (score 0):

Heyoffline is no AMD module. I think the problem is that [require.js](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) is waiting until `Heyoffline` is loaded. Which is in this case defined on **global scope** AND on **window scope**. The `exports` property finds the **global** value first, but in your `define`, you need to **window** value, which is not loaded yet.

There are **two possible solutions** (untested, since I haven't used Heyoffline):

**1) Adapt Heyoffline**

Try the change heyoffline.js with the following. Change `window.Heyoffline` by `window.Heyoffline2` (at the end of the file):

```
return window.Heyoffline2 = new Heyoffline;
```

Change your shim accordingly:

```
shim: {
        'heyoffline': {
            exports: 'Heyoffline2'
        }
    }
```

**2) Use domReady plugin**

Another possibility you can try, is to use plugin [domReady](http://requirejs.org/docs/download.html#domReady). Also remove the `Heyoffline` parameter from the function, and use `window.Heyoffline` to make sure you use the correct object:

```
define(["domReady!heyoffline"], function () {
  new window.Heyoffline;
}
```

Comment: it doesn't look like a pretty solution to me

Comment: Heyoffline is not AMD compliant. First you need to know if what I described is the cause of the problem. The easiest way to know is what I suggested. If it solves it, you could possibly contact the creator of Heyoffline.